# I want to Access to a modem/router through QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, command, telnet, qtcpsocket

When i use a program(just console) like putty i can access to 192.168.x.x and it shows user/pass to enter//, this helps to do some tweaking to the DSL Line (Snr Margin ... etc)

```
void testtcp::connect(){
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost("192.168.x.x",23);
    if(socket->waitForConnected(1000)){
        qDebug() <<"Connected";
        socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        qDebug()<<"Reading.."<<socket->bytesAvailable();
        qDebug()<<"Reading.."<<socket->readAll();

    }else{
        qDebug()<<"Not connected";
    }
}
```

but it just says connected only and receiving some misunderstood hex words ..
if i do the same in command menu it works but in my program not!!
how to make it open like this picture

[image]

Comment: Putty uses the SSH protocol to communicate with the router, and that protocol obviously has rules for initiating communication, requesting credentials, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much bro <3 , i tried the same without putty . opening command menu as administrator and writing this command open 192.168.x.x 23 it open the same! so both are using SSH Protocol? is there any advices?

Comment: Find out which protocols your router supports and implement the rules of that protocol.

Comment: Thank you bro <3 really this helped me a lot , i am  just a beginner now i have something to search for  (protocols) <3 really many thanks